# SQL error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got "error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" trying to execute this Query:

```
SELECT id FROM postcodes WHERE pcd LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(pcd,' %') FROM towns WHERE id IN (31898,12828,15771,7604))
```

do you have any suggestion for this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables instead of the `IN` predicate, like this:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM postcodes p
INNER JOIN towns t ON p.pcd LIKE CONCAT(t.pcd,' %')
WHERE t.id IN (31898,12828,15771,7604);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this query :

```
SELECT CONCAT(pcd,' %') FROM towns WHERE id IN (31898,12828,15771,7604)
```

Maybe it's result is more than one row.

Or you can limit the subquery result.

```
SELECT id FROM postcodes WHERE pcd LIKE (SELECT CONCAT(pcd,' %') FROM towns WHERE id IN (31898,12828,15771,7604) LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: actually i don't want to limit, if i wanted to limit those results i would not us IN statement! i can execute this query for each of these id's separately but it's not efficient i want to know if there is an efficient query that can do this SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You have to LIMIT the sub-query to one row. Either You should add some filters to limit the result to one row or adding `LIMIT 1` to your sub-query will do the trick for you.

Comment: actually i don't want to limit, if i wanted to limit those results i would not us IN statement! i can execute this query for each of these id's separately but it's not efficient i want to know if there is an efficient query that can do this SELECT.